# subprocess capture output of first 60 seconds

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a long running process (k8s job with logs) that I wish to run via `subprocess.check_output`. I only care about the output of the command in the first 60 seconds, so I've done this:

```py
out = subprocess.check_output(
    shlex.split(command),
    timeout=60,
)
```

However, since the process runs for longer it ends with this exception. `raise TimeoutExpired( subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command ...` . Is there a way to simply terminate the command at 60 seconds and capture the output. The output is important as I wish to do some post processing of the output in the first 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own replacement using bare `Popen` but it's kind of cumbersome.  Basically cribbing from [Read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate) and adding a timeout;

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=60)
with Popen(
    shlex.split(command), stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
    text=True, check=True
) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
        if datetime.now() >= deadline:
           break
```

Obviously, you can do something else with the output than `print` it -- probably collect it into a list so you can examine it after the loop.

The `check=True` is vaguely useless here, but mimics the behavior of `check_output` in that it will raise an exception if the subprocess fails. It would guard against typos in `command` etc, of course.